# Android dev: Share animated Gif from Internal Storage

Tags: android, animation, share, gif, animated-gif

I want to share animated gif images that are in my drawable folder.
The code works so far, but the shared gif file is not animated. You can only see the first image of the animation. Does someone know how it could work?

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.animated_gif);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/gif");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + "temporary_file.gif");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.gif"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are geting **static** bitmap from drawable. I recomend you to use GifDrawable in Glide library and this approach for sending animated gifs (in case you loaded your gif image into ImageView):

```
private Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView, String link) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof GifDrawable) {
        try {
            // Store image to default external storage directory
            String fileName = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, link.length());
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "shared_gif_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            GifDrawable gifDrawable = ((GifDrawable) imageView.getDrawable());
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(gifDrawable.getData());
            out.close();
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

...
Uri bmpUri = Utils.getLocalBitmapUri(gifImageView, post.media_content.get(0).file);
if (bmpUri != null) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/gif");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "title");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
} else {
    // ...sharing failed, handle error
}
...
```

Comment: gifDrawable.getData()? There is no such method, how do I get the data?